# Как совместить два списка и получить список пар, по одному значению из каждого входного списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два списка:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Как, например, сделать так

```
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Решение использующее [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [25]: l1 = [1,2,3,4]

In [26]: l2 = [11,22,33,44]

In [27]: [list(tup) for tup in zip(l1, l2)]
Out[27]: [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
```

Решение использующее [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html):

```
In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: l1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [17]: l2 = np.array([11,22,33,44])

In [18]: a = np.c_[l1, l2]

In [19]: a
Out[19]:
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 22],
       [ 3, 33],
       [ 4, 44]])
```

как обычный список:

```
In [20]: a.tolist()
Out[20]: [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
```

Решение использующее [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
In [28]: import pandas as pd

In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4]})

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   col1
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4

In [30]: df['col2'] = [11,22,33,44]

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
   col1  col2
0     1    11
1     2    22
2     3    33
3     4    44

In [34]: df.values.tolist()
Out[34]: [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33], [4, 44]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.append(value)

список_из_списков = [[1],[2]]
добавляемое_значение = 1

for список in список_из_списков:
    список.append(добавляемое_значение)

# или генератор
результат = [список.append(добавляемое_значение) for список in список_из_списков]
```